# How does a webserver know what website you want to access?

Tags: http, web

Apache has something called VirtualHosts.
You can configure it in that way that when you go to example.com get a different site than example2.com even if you use the same IP's.
A HTTP Request looks something like this:

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.0
[some more]
```

How does the server know you are trying to access www.example.com or www.example2.com?

Comment: The "[some more]" there is what's important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the GET line, the browser sends a number of headers. One of these headers is the `Host` header, which specifies which host the request is targeted at.

A simple example request could be:

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.0
Host: example.com
```

This indicates that the browser wants whatever is at `http://example.com/index.html`, and not what is at `http://example2.com/index.html`.

#### Further information:

- [The `Host` header in the HTTP specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.23)

Answer (score 0):

IIS also has this and I believe refers to it as host header redirection.

The http packet header contains the destination hostname which the server uses to determine which website to serve up. Some more reading: http://www.it-notebook.org/iis/article/understanding_host_headers.htm